# How can i validate jquery Regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
const input = [
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dd314"}, 
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dc152"},
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dbf09"}
];

input.forEach(({q}) => $(`[data-id="${q}"]`).css("background", "lime"));
```

How can i validate on (q) value Regular expression ?

I want use regex code in this way because my value it's always changing.

Meanwhile I am using that code on Greasemonkey.

```
{q: "5..........................bf09"}
```

Comment: Using try / catch statement and trying to 'just-a-test'.match(q) > If it doesn't fail it's ok.
(OK as in technically OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to apply a regex which checks that the `q` value starts with `5` and ends with `bf09`.  I don't know how to phrase this without using an explicit anonymous function:

```
input.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.match(/^5.{19}bf09$/)) {
        $(`[data-id="${element}"]`).css("background", "lime"));
    }
})
```

Comment: @Nikola You just changed your question.  Try the pattern `^5.{19}bf09$`.